# Insert multiple records if table is empty

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot, h2, mybatis

I have a scenario where I have to insert multiple records if the table is empty. My sql script runs everytime I run my server. I don't use H2 database so that I can insert on duplicate key. I use myBatis. I want the query to insert only if the table is empty.

My insert query is as follows:

```
LOCK TABLES `t002_seat_mst` WRITE;
INSERT INTO `t002_seat_mst` VALUES (2020,1,1,0,0,1,0,'228A'),(2021,1,2,0,0,1,0,'229A'),
    (2022,1,3,0,0,1,0,'231A'),(2023,1,4,0,0,1,0,'233A'),(2024,1,5,0,0,1,0,'235A'),
    (2025,1,6,0,0,1,0,'237A'),(2026,1,7,0,0,1,0,'239A'),(2027,1,8,0,0,1,0,'240A'),
    (2028,1,9,0,0,1,0,'242A'),(2029,1,10,0,0,1,0,'244A'),(2030,1,11,0,0,1,0,'246A');
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: "...My sql script runs everytime I run my server..." -- What do you mean by that? When you restart the box, the engine?

Comment: It means, whenever I run my application the script gets executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test

```
LOCK TABLES `t002_seat_mst` AS t1 WRITE, `t002_seat_mst` AS t2 READ;

INSERT INTO t002_seat_mst AS t1
SELECT * 
FROM ( SELECT 2020 a,1 b,1 c,0 d,0 e,1 f,0 g,'228A' h UNION ALL
       SELECT 2021,1,2,0,0,1,0,'229A' UNION ALL
       SELECT 2022,1,3,0,0,1,0,'231A' UNION ALL
       SELECT 2023,1,4,0,0,1,0,'233A' UNION ALL
       SELECT 2024,1,5,0,0,1,0,'235A' UNION ALL
       SELECT 2025,1,6,0,0,1,0,'237A' UNION ALL
       SELECT 2026,1,7,0,0,1,0,'239A' UNION ALL
       SELECT 2027,1,8,0,0,1,0,'240A' UNION ALL
       SELECT 2028,1,9,0,0,1,0,'242A' UNION ALL
       SELECT 2029,1,10,0,0,1,0,'244A' UNION ALL
       SELECT 2030,1,11,0,0,1,0,'246A' ) data
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM t002_seat_mst AS t2 );

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: Great that you combined `NULL` with `EXISTS`. +1

Comment: Hi Akina, I have this query under lock and unlock tables. This is giving an error stating `Table 't002_seat_mst' was not locked with LOCK TABLES`

Comment: @Subham *This is giving an error stating* Do you use my query in some code block (procedure, function, event, etc.) where LOCK TABLES statement is used?

Comment: Yes @Akina. I am using the query in `schema.sql`  file which contains lock and unlock table statements. I have edited the question. Please have a look.

Comment: @Subham When you use LOCK-UNLOCK block you must mention ALL table copies in LOCK TABLE statement which are accessed in this block with proper lock type. If some query uses more than one table copy then you must assign unique alias to each copy and lock each alias. So give 2 different aliases to 2 copies of `t002_seat_mst` table (in UPDATE and in subquery's FROM) and use proper LOCK types for them. This is well-described in [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html#table-lock-acquisition) (2nd example). Code updated.

Comment: @Akina it worked . great thanks. I have made a small change to the syntax. `LOCK TABLES `t002_seat_mst` WRITE, `t002_seat_mst` AS t2 READ;`.

Comment: @Subham It doesn't matter. But I'd recommend always give aliases to all tables in a query/block when more than one table and/or table copy is used - this allows to distinguish what table is each field taken from easily.

Comment: Sure @Akina. Will use it from now on